# In VMWare fusion Pro, why I can not map an IP address to "localhost"?

Tags: localhost, virtual-machine, vmware

I am running a web application in the host machine and accessing it from Window 8 running in VMWare fusion Pro for the purpose of testing my application with IE11.

I have set up Custom Network Connection so that my host IP address in the virtual machine has a Subnet IP: 172.16.201.0

[screenshot of VMWare fusion Pro network setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/It0NF.png)

With that I am able to access my web application in the guest with:

```
http://172.16.201.1:9999
```

Notice in the above, for the reason I don't understand, I have to offset the last digit by 1 (172.16.201.0 does not work).

Since I want to to access the application from guest machine with the url "http://localhost:9999", I added the above subnet ip address to my guest machine 's c:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts:

```
172.16.201.1 localhost
```

With that however, I have no access to my application at "http://localhost:9999" from IE11 in the virtual machine. And it is very strange that I will have access if I had configured c:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts to anything else as long as it is not "localhost". For example if I were using:

```
172.16.201.1 host
```

I can access my application with "http://host:9999". In fact, any name would work as long as it is not "localhost"

[screenshot of window 8 running in VMWare fusion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EPpbs.png)

I noticed the following note commented out in the original  "c:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts" that says:

```
# localhost name resolution is handled within DNS itself.
#   127.0.0.1       localhost
#   ::1             localhost
```

I am not sure what it means but seem like it is trying to tell me "localhost" should be map in DNS ? If this is the case where is the DNS configuration so I can map "localhost' to the Custom Subnet IP address ?

Thanks for helping